# how to get the tray button text wiht ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c#, readprocessmemory

I want to get all tray icons on windows7(64bit) with C#,but when i used the windows api "ReadProcessMemory" ,the tray button Text can't be recognied.
codes below

```
        IntPtr pid = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero; 
        IntPtr lTextAdr = IntPtr.Zero; 

        IntPtr ipTray = TrayToolbarWindow32();

        WinApiHelper.GetWindowThreadProcessId(ipTray, ref pid);
        if (pid.Equals(0))
            return iconList;

        IntPtr hProcess = WinApiHelper.OpenProcess(WinApiHelper.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS | WinApiHelper.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | WinApiHelper.PROCESS_VM_READ | WinApiHelper.PROCESS_VM_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, pid);

        IntPtr lAddress = WinApiHelper.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, 4096, WinApiHelper.MEM_COMMIT, WinApiHelper.PAGE_READWRITE);


        int lButton = WinApiHelper.SendMessage(ipTray, WinApiHelper.TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < lButton; i++)
        {

            WinApiHelper.SendMessage(ipTray, WinApiHelper.TB_GETBUTTON, i, lAddress);


            WinApiHelper.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (IntPtr)(lAddress.ToInt32() + 16), ref lTextAdr, 4, 0);

            if (!lTextAdr.Equals(-1))
            {
                byte[] buff = new byte[ 1024 ];

                WinApiHelper.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lTextAdr, buff, 1024, 0);
                string title = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buff);
```

and api declaration

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
    public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, ref IntPtr lpBuffer, int nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemoryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, IntPtr size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
    public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

the problem is here

```
string title = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buff);
```

when converted , the string "title" can't be recognized,it maybe like

```
ǎ\0\0\0\0Д\0\0à\0\0ƿ\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D:\\Tools\\ESET Smart Security\\egui.exe\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
```

i don't know why, help.

Comment: This code cannot work properly on a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider what you are doing.  `ReadProcessMemory` is a debug function designed for debuggers which requires `SeDebugPrivilege`, so I hope you are writing a debugger.  Ignoring the queasiness I get from considering use of these functions in a non-debug capacity, you are leaking the buffer you allocated and requiring that your application run as administrator.

If this application is only for your own purposes and for no-one else, then check out the related question [Systray Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264281/systray-access), as it seems that there is a separate TB_GETBUTTONTEXT message.  I imagine that you are actually receiving the button data, rather than text in the copied memory, causing issues.